# Access FormGroupDirective of container component inside an embeddedView

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Getting more and more insights on how reactive forms actually work, from time to time I still trying to figure out what actually happens and how to make a certain scenario happen. For example I'm currently trying to create a reusable component and add input fields via an embedded view.

Unfortunately, I always get an error about how my formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. To prevent this error from happening even before the content has been projected, I wrapped the content in a ng-template and move its instanciaqtion to the child component which shows the projected content. But still it complains about not having a form group directive present.

My question therefore is: How is ng-content or ng-template being handled in terms of injectors and could you please point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong?

I also tried to create a directive, put it on the ng-container and injected the existingFormGroup directive via `providers: [{providers: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}]`. Without any luck.

To better understand whats actually going on, I've created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuvbrg

Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: What is `aForm` and where do you instantiate it? is your goal to create the formGroup in the parent component and pass it to `FormListItemComponent` as an input?

Comment: Or should `aForm` be `formListItemForm: FormGroup`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's fixed.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure I understood correctly... sometimes just need an extra set of eyes is all.

Comment: the problem is that the contents of `ng-template` always belongs to the component where it's declared, not the component to which it's projected to. In your case the search for a parent form's provider starts from the AppComponent view, not the from the [element injector of the `form` directive](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-curios-case-of-the-host-decorator-and-element-injectors-in-angular-582562abcf0a#8df4) inside `FormListItemComponent`. Consider using a dynamic component instead of an embedded view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created views Angular distinguishes two types:

- *declaration view* - a view where the template was declared
- *insertion view* - a view where the template was inserted

And the main rule here is that 
***the context is inherited from
   the declaration view tree, not the insertion view tree.***

It means that having a template like:

```
<app-form-list-item>
  <ng-template #someChild>
    <input type="text" formControlName="myUsername">
  </ng-template>
</app-form-list-item>
```

we should make sure that `formControlName` directive can find `ControlContainer` dependency climbing up tree starting from this template not template inside `app-form-list-item`.

Putting any directives with ControlContainer provider in `form-list-item.component.html` won't help here because formControlName is declared in parent component.

One workaround, that might be possible here and that won't require writing code in parent component, is to provide `ControlContainer` on your `FormListItemComponent`:

**form-list-item.component.html**

```
<form #ngForm="ngForm" ...
```

**form-list-item.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: (comp: FormListItemComponent) => comp.ngForm,
      deps: [FormListItemComponent] 
    }
  ]
})
export class FormListItemComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  ...
  @ViewChild('ngForm') ngForm: FormGroupDirective;
```

It will result in

```
<app-form-list-item>    <=== ControlContainer that points to inner FormGroupDirective
 /\
 ||   <ng-template #someChild>
 ||
 ||     <input type="text" formControlName="myUsername">
```

And it will only work if you wrap the content in a template otherwise `ControlContainer` will point to empty FormGroupDirective

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftmmfl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-list-item%2Fform-list-item.component.ts)**

See also:

- **[What you always wanted to know about Angular Dependency Injection tree](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-dependency-injection-and-tree-shakeable-tokens-4588a8f70d5d?gi=c1b2008c527f)**